# C++ WINAPI CreateDIBitmap trouble

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, paint, dib

I wrote a program which loads a bitmap file (only) to a window, and it's works fine for any file with `.bmp` extansion. But I faced with the next problem when I was making a testing. I took a file with `.jpg` extansion, opened it in `Paint` and then saved it as a BMP file. When I was starting a test with this new file, my program loaded a black window.

I made a debug and find out that `biColorUsed` field of `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure is zero. According to [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this means that

> the bitmap uses the maximum number of colors corresponding to the value of the biBitCount
>   member for the compression mode specified by biCompression.

`biCompression` field is also zero which means that file is uncompressed.

`biBitCount` is equal to 24 which means (according to same docs) that

> The bmiColors color table is used for optimizing colors used on palette-based devices, and
>   must contain the number of entries specified by the biClrUsed member of the 
>   BITMAPINFOHEADER

It couldn't be specified because `biClrUsed` is zero.

So, the question is, is `BMP` file created by a conversion of `JPG` file using `Paint` realy a `BMP` file?

P. S.
I use CreateDIBitmap function in my program. When I load the same `BMP` file using LoadImage, it works fine.
Any other fields of structures `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is loaded correctly. That's why I think that I properly load data from `BMP` file. I could upload my project on  GoogleDrive and then share it if this would be needed.

Comment: what are the first four bytes of the image file?

Comment: @meklarian first two bytes is a `bfType` field of `BITMAPFILEHEADER` which is equal to 19778 which is "BM". Second field is a `bfSize` which is equal to 1537078. It's first byte is 36 in hexodemical, second one is 74. I guess I didn't understand your question correctly)

Comment: @meklarian The first four are 42, 4d, ffffffcc, ffffffcc.

Comment: merely curious whether the fourCC of the file (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC ) corresponds to one of the well-known BMP markers. if the first three bytes happened to correspond to 'JPG' or something else, then that would explain your issue right-away.

Comment: @meklarian I didn't know about fourCC, thanks)

Comment: a full list is available here: http://www.fourcc.org/ , you should see a match in here that may explain what kind of output you are getting: http://www.fourcc.org/rgb.php